# How differentiate DeltaTime (VLQ) from Running Status, Midi Specification

Tags: midi, specifications

I was reading this article: https://www.midikits.net/midi_analyser/running_status.htm

[image]

I'm reading a MIDI File, here the last snippet in bytes:

```
00 B2 07 64    00 0A 40 00
5B 00 00 5D    00 00 FF 21
01 00 83 5F    90 3C 00 01
FF 2F 00
```

https://www.midi.org/downloads?task=callelement&format=raw&item_id=92&element=f85c494b-2b32-4109-b8c1-083cca2b7db6&method=download

Reading page 91, `Delta Time` apparently is not sent, instead send Two bytes related with "Running Status"

[image]

Here my interpretation (I know is bad due to I not considered Running Status)

```
00 B2 07 64 
    // track event size: '4', delta time: '0', event: 'status byte 'B2', 
    // data length: '2', data: '0764', description: 'Controller Change', 
    // channel: '2 - Midi Event Type'
00 0A // track event size: '2', delta time: '0', event: ' - '
40 00 // track event size: '2', delta time: '64', event: ' - '
5B 00 // track event size: '2', delta time: '91', event: ' - '
00 5D // track event size: '2', delta time: '0', event: ' - '
00 00 // track event size: '2', delta time: '0', event: ' - '
FF 21 01 // track event size: '3', delta time: '16289', event: ' - '
00 83 5F 90 
    // delta time: '0', event: 'status byte '83', data length: '2', data: '5F90', 
    // description: 'Note Off', channel: '3 - Midi Event Type'
3C 00 // track event size: '2', delta time: '60', event: ' - '
01 FF 2F 00 
    //track event size: '4', delta time: '1', event: 'type: '2F', 
    // data length: '0', data: '', description: 'End of Track - Meta Event Type'
```

As you can see in `00 0A` line `00` is treated like Delta Time, but `0A` Is not related to some Event Type. (I think it's a Running Status), the same Situation happens with `3C 00` line.

**Question:**

What is the clue to differentiate When is *Running Status* and when is `delta time`?

**EDIT 1:**

In my example can be interpreted like `Control Changes Messages`:

```
   0A 40 // 0A Pan
```

Check the Example related in the web link.

Suppose the same `Delta Time` `00`

```
00  // Delta Time
   90 3C 7F // Note ON, Channel 0, Key 3C , Velocity 7F
00  // Delta Time
   90 40 7F // Note ON, Channel 0, Key 40 , Velocity 7F
00  // Delta Time
   90 43 7F // Note ON, Channel 0, Key 43 , Velocity 7F
```

Before example is transformed like

```
00  // Delta Time
   90 3C 7F // Note ON, Channel 0, Key 3C , Velocity 7F
00  // Delta Time
   40 7F // Note ON, Channel 0, Key 40 , Velocity 7F
00  // Delta Time
   43 7F // Note ON, Channel 0, Key 43 , Velocity 7F
```

But, As I do not to confuse with [CONTROL CHANGE MESSAGES (DATA BYTES)](https://www.midi.org/specifications/item/table-3-control-change-messages-data-bytes-2)

```
  40 7F // 40   Damper Pedal on/off (Sustain)

  43 7F // 43   Soft Pedal On/Off
```

Answer (score 2):

Inside a track, every event is prefixed with a delta time value. The length of the delta time value is obvious: it ends with the byte that does not have the most significant bit set.

The length of the MIDI event itself is determined by the status byte. When using running status, the previous status byte is used. Status bytes and data bytes can be differentiated by the most significant bit.
When you have read a delta time, and the next byte does not have the MSB set, you have running status, and must read as many data bytes as needed by the event:

```
00             delta time
   B2 07 64    control change: volume = 100
00             delta time
      0A 40    (running status) expression = 64
00             delta time
      5B 00    (running status) reverb = 0
00             delta time
      5D 00    (running status) chorus = 0
00             delta time
   FF 21 01 00 meta event: port number = 0
83 5F          delta time
   90 3C 00    note-off
01             delta time
   FF 2F 00    meta event: end of track
```

Comment: Thank you, I found the interpretation for Running Status... https://www.midi.org/specifications/item/table-3-control-change-messages-data-bytes-2

Comment: Running status can be used for any event type; you have to remember the last actual status byte.

Comment: But, How know which interpretation must be applied when you are reading bytes from file? has Control Change Messages or Running Status any limitation? (to not have ambiguos data bytes)

Comment: There is only one interpretation. To repeat myself: you have to remember the last actual status byte. In your example, that byte is B2.

Comment: Then When I got a `Status Byte` due to `Midi Event` always I can to interpreted like `Running Status` or what exception exists? But when I haven't  `Status Byte` like `Meta Event`  or`Sysex Event` always I can interpret like `Control Change Messages`.

Comment: There are no exceptions; running status is allowed only for channel messages.

Comment: it is can be ruler. If I have unidentified Two bytes following a `Midi Event` always will be `Running Status` for another events type like `Sysex Event` or `Meta Event` will be `Control Changes Messages`. Is it true?

Comment: Running status can be used for any channel message (90..EF), but not for anything else.

Comment: Thankyou for you answers, But for me it is not clear yet.